# Sending and Retrieving Files to a Server with Python

Tags: python, file, heroku, server

I'm working on a small project in python where the user should be able to upload files to a server and other users can read those files from their client.

So far I've tried using sockets but I realised that would only work locally. I've been reading up on services such as PythonAnywhere and Heroku where I could potentially run my server.py.

I'm just stuck on how to get started. I'm starting to think there is a better way but I have no clue where to begin. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere dev here: have you considered writing a simple web app?  Web frameworks like Django and Flask have support for uploading files via web pages, or you could build something using an HTTP-based API.  Downloading files would be pretty easy too.